"pip install github" fails
I am unable to install the package github from PyPI.
So the problem is I want to use
from github import Github

But I after trying pip install github
I am getting an error:
Building wheels for collected packages: aiohttp
  Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for aiohttp (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [100 lines of output]
      *********************
      * Accelerated build *
      *********************
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\abc.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\base_protocol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_proto.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_reqrep.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\client_ws.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\connector.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\cookiejar.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\formdata.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\hdrs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_parser.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_websocket.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\http_writer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\locks.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\multipart.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\payload.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\payload_streamer.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\pytest_plugin.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\resolver.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\streams.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\tcp_helpers.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\test_utils.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\tracing.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\typedefs.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_app.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_exceptions.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_fileresponse.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_log.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_middlewares.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_protocol.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_request.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_response.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_routedef.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_runner.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_server.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_urldispatcher.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\web_ws.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\worker.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      running egg_info
      writing aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
      writing dependency_links to aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
      writing requirements to aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
      writing top-level names to aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
      reading manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
      warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
      warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
      no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
      adding license file 'LICENSE.txt'
      writing manifest file 'aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
      copying aiohttp\_cparser.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_find_header.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_find_header.h -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_find_header.pxd -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_headers.pxi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_helpers.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyi -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_helpers.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_parser.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_parser.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_writer.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_http_writer.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_websocket.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\_websocket.pyx -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      copying aiohttp\py.typed -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_cparser.pxd.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_find_header.pxd.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyi.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_helpers.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_parser.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_http_writer.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\_websocket.pyx.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp\.hash
      copying aiohttp\.hash\hdrs.py.hash -> build\lib.win-amd64-cpython-311\aiohttp\.hash
      running build_ext
      building 'aiohttp._websocket' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for aiohttp
Failed to build aiohttp
ERROR: Could not build wheels for aiohttp, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I tried downgrading from python=3.12 to python=3.11.
And as github requires aiohttp=3.8.2 I've done that too.
But I still get the same error.
I want to use Github and want to clone multiple repositories at a time using GitHub Access Tokens.
I expected downgrading would solve the issue.

For the record, this was repeatedly closed as a duplicate of Error "Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required (Unable to find vcvarsall.bat)" but as there is an answer which is specific to aiohttp which avoids that problem altogether, perhaps this should remain open.

Read the error message.

@wim would you mind re-opening this question? I have a potentially better answer, but I can't write that now. (It involves using another aiohttp version, since 3.8.2 as yanked from pypi; no wonder it can't be installed.)

GitHub requires aiohttp >= 3.8.1 and there are several versions avail which are not yanked, pip should figure that out by itself. The correct answer still seems to be installing the build deps.

@wim GitHub, yes, that's my point. The PyPI version, however, does not, as it fixes the aiohttp version, and the OP installs from PyPI, not from GitHub. This is part of my answer: use the GitHub version, not the PyPI one. That saves the hassle of installing C++ and building it oneself.

@9769953 Ok, I see what you're saying now - the github 1.2.7 release on PyPI has the constraint aiohttp==3.8.1, which means pip on python=3.12 is forced to use an sdist aiohttp-3.8.1.tar.gz and won't use a wheel. I'm not sure why they pin in the pkg metadata with ==, that's unusual and problematic. Will reopen, go ahead and write the better answer.

As I searched on internet, I also tried degrading python to 3.11 and then tried. But same issue.

@tripleee Did you read the comments? There was a reason the question was reopened, as I think there is a better solution for this particular problem.

@9769953 Sorry, just came across this cold and didn't notice you had reopened it.

The release of github on PyPI has its aiohttp requirement fixed to version 3.8.1 (not 3.8.2, which is what you note), but the main branch on GitHub has loosened this requirement to aiohttp>=3.8.1. So try with a direct installation from GitHub instead, to avoid the strict aiohttp requirement:
python -m pip install git+https://github.com/VarMonke/GitHub-API-Wrapper.git

That way, you can install github with a more recent, and more importantly, prebuilt version of aiohttp, avoiding having to install the C++ build tools and building it yourself.
The likely reason behind your problems is that aiohttp versions 3.8.1 and 3.8.2 don't have a prebuilt version for Python 3.11 and 3.12. With the above installation, you'll get a newer version of aiohttp, which does have such builds.

Did you try downloading the C++ build tools at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/ ?
It looks like that would fix it.

But I am getting error with Python and I am not sure how to fix it with the C++ build tool

Python is built on top of C++. So this extension needs the C++ build tools. You wont be using the C++ build tools directly you just need to have them installed.

@Noel Minor nitpick: Python is written in (and built with) C, not C++. It's just so that the MS C++ build tools can compile C code as well.
